# Water bonding AND grounding rods

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, grounding-and-bonding

Upgrading to 400 amp service. Have already set my two grounding rods and ran #2 solid for them.

My question is about the water bonding.

Existing water bond was (to my understanding) done wrong...but not noticed on inspection. It was attached to a hose bib on the opposite side of the house (60') from where the pipe enters the ground. At the time the whole house was copper piping.

Piping now changes to pex just AFTER it enters the house, so I am assuming that it does actually still need bonded...

That being the case...What size wire for the 30' run from the panel to the closest qualifying bonding point?

Water main is metallic and will remain so.

Comment: You may want to double-check with your jurisdiction (electrical permit or building permit department). Some places are still doing the water pipe bond, some have switched to *only* ground rods due to the prevalence of PEX, etc.

Comment: Is your water main still copper/metallic, or is that going to be changed to plastic as well?

Comment: My mains are copper and will remain so.

Comment: Also, the language seems to suggest that, because the pipe enters the building (even if its only 6"), I need to bond it. But, having consulted with my inspector, he said not to bother. No explanation for what seems (to me) like it would be an exception, just..."I wouldn't bother".

Comment: Exactly what I thought might (50%) happen. Local practices have a **lot** to do with this. My guess is that *new* buildings are being built with the water main *not* metal, so rather than pick and choose based on each situation, they just established a local rule of "two ground rods, no water pipe".

Answer (score 1):

Size of Grounding Electrode Conductor feeding metal water piping entering a building is based on size of ungrounded Service Entrance conductors from Table 250.66.

[image]

For a 400A Service I would expect you would need 400CU/600AL kcm service conductors so you would need 1/0 copper for the water pipe grounding electrode.

[image]

Comment: Strange, I thought the revisions stated never larger than 2/0.